# Text in URL after slash as parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to create htaccess rule to turn this url:
**www.foo.com/?val=hello**
to:
**www.foo.com/hello**

I created new rule but It is not working.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+|)/?$ index.php?s=$1 [QSA]
```

Any ideas how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: With QSA, it would redirect to `www.foo.com/hello?val=hello`.  QSA appends the query string at the end of the rewritten URL, causing a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

I did this on my Apache:

- Setup index.phtml.  It is define as DirectoryIndex in httpd.conf.
- Setup hello.phtml
- In my httpd.conf, in the appropriate VirtualHost, I added this:

  ```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "val=(.+)"
  RewriteRule "(.*)"  "%1?"    [L,R=302]
  ```
- If I ask for http://localhost/?var=hello.phtml, I get redirected to http://localhost/hello.phtml.

Details:

- RewriteEngine on: turn on the rewriting engine.  Remember to load the rewrite module (`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`)
- RewriteCond: variable **%{QUERY_STRING}** contains everything Apache received after `?`.  I match this to `val=(.+)`.  `.` matches anything, `+` means "one or more of the preceding".  The preceding here is `.`, so any combination of characters is valid.  It is put in parenthesis since I will need that matched group later.
- RewriteRule:  `"(.*)"` matches anything after `http://localhost/`.  It is replaced by `%1`, which here contains what was enclosed in parenthesis in the RewriteCond above.  Then I added `?` to ensure the query string is not added.

Note about the `?`.  By default, if you rewrite from `.../somepage.html?var1=value1` to `.../somepage2.html`, the rewrite engine will automatically add `?var1=value1` at the end of it.  To rewrite without keeping the query string, add a single `?` at the end.

- L: in case you have other rules later, this indicates that it is the last rule to consider if it matches.
- R=302.  Here I return a 302, temporarily moved.  if you want the redirect to be permanent, put R=301.